# Почему «рыбОлов», но рыбАк?

Tags: орфография, морфемный-разбор

Почему пишется *рыб**о**лов*, хотя *рыб**а**, рыб**а**чка, рыб**а**чить* и т. д.?

Answer (score 8):

В слове *рыба* а - это окончание, оно образует форму слова, а в образовании новых слов обычно не участвует. Рыб**ак** - суффикс -**ак,** в слове рыб**ач**ка - тот же суфффикс  плюс суффикс **к**, в слове рыболов - **о** является соединительной гласной. Т.е. это разные морфемы, проверять написание одной морфемы с помощью другой неправильно.

Answer (score 7):

Корень **-рыб-** (ср. *рыб*ный суп), соединительная гласная **-о-** и второй корень **-лов-** (ср. *лов*ить).

Answer (score 1):

Слово РЫБОЛОВ-сложное слово с двумя корнями- РЫБ-  и _ЛОВ-,а между ними соединительная гласная -О.  Есть всего 2 соединительных гласных- О и Е. Так я помню из школьной программы.небОсвод,вездЕход и пр.